# T4MVC - Dealing with optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm using .NET 3.5, MVC 2 and T4MVC 2.6.42...

I have the following action:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(string id, int page = 1)
```

And the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Products", // Route name
    "Products/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new string[] { "Web.Controllers" }
);
```

But when I try to call `MVC.Products.Index("anything")` I get a "No overload for method 'Index' takes '1' arguments" exception. Calling `MVC.Products.Index()`, however, works.

Shouldn't I be able to omit the "page" parameter since it defaults to '1'?

**Note:** I've tried defaulting the page parameter to 1 in the route, didn't work.

**Note 2:** Also tried the [[Optional] Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.optionalattribute.aspx) with no success.

Comment: Can we see the full stack trace?

Comment: @KirkWoll Sorry, I managed to find the solution. Apparently, optional arguments are a C# 4.0 thing (the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) states VS2010). Oddly enough, I don't get a compiler error when I declare a method like that in C# 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my response to Kirk Woll above, apparently, [optional parameters aren't supported in C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

I solved the problem by creating an overload and using the [NonAction Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute.aspx):

```
[NonAction]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return Index(id, 1);
}
```

Then MVC.Products.Index("foo") works like a charm, with any C# version.

Answer (score 5):

Though you figured out the problem with the wrong C# version, for future reference there is a way of doing this. You can write:

```
MVC.Products.Index().AddRouteValue("id", "anything");
```

This lets you add the value for individual param in addition to what the method call passes in.

Comment: That's one way to do it. I'll post the solution I've found (I couldn't before because I had to wait 24h before posting an answer to my own question).

Answer (score 0):

Just make your int nullable and it will work.

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(string id, int? page = 1)
```

Comment: Then I'll have to pass null every time, which, in this particular case, is pretty much the same as passing the default value. Actually it was my first approach, but then I grew sick of calling MVC.Products.Index("foo",null).

Comment: but you can call MVC.Products.Index("foo")